# Is there a test error metric that takes into account variance of the data?

Tags: machine-learning, meta-analysis, hyperparameter, meta-regression

In standard machine learning applications, models are often evaluated based on metrics like RMSE or Deviance. I was wondering if there is a similar metric tailored towards meta-analyses that takes into account not just the value of a data point, but its variance as well? So deviations between the model and the data are penalized less for data points with low variance compared to those with higher variance.

Comment: That's what a random effects meta-analysis does.

Comment: You can create your own metric e.g. RMSE + std(RMSE)